# Incompatible types error: Manipulating return value of another class's method

Tags: java, android, class, methods

I need to yield a `JsonObject` in a class `MainActivity` from a method `doInBackground()` in a class `Post`.

I instantiated the class `Post`, called the method in it which is being passed parameters into, and tried to assign it to a variable of type `JSONObject`.

This is the class `Post`:

```
class Post extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        try {
            //Connect to the website
            Connection.Response response =
                    Jsoup.connect(args[0])
                            .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                            .data("text", args[1])
                            .data("language", args[2])
                            .ignoreContentType(true)
                            .execute();
            Document document = response.parse();
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(document.text());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException err) {
            Log.d("Error", err.toString());
        }
        return jsonObject;
    }
}
```

And this is how I tried to retrieve the object in the class `MainActivity`:

```
Post post = new Post();
JSONObject object = post.execute(stringurl, text, "en");
```

The Java error I get is incompatible types. Required is `org.json.JSONObject` and found is `android.os.AsyncTask <java.lang.String, java.lang.Void, org.json.JSONObject>`.

I should be able to capture the `JSONObject`... how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a method in `MainActivity` which can be called from the `AsyncTask` once it has fetched the `JSONObject`:

```
private onObtainJSONObject(JSONObject jsonObject){
    if(jsonObject != null){
        // do something with the JSONObject
    } else{
        // something went wrong - maybe show an error message?
    }
}
```

And you need to override `onPostExecute()` in the `AsyncTask`:

```
public void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject){
    // Note: this will be executed on the main thread
    MainActivity.this.onObtainJSONObject(jsonObject);
}
```

If the `AsyncTask` is not an inner class of your `Activity`, you can use a callback (a simple interface)  as follows

```
public interface PostCallback{
    void onSuccess(JSONObject data);
    void onError(Exception exception);
}
```

Then you let the `AsyncTask` have a field of type `PostCallback` and a setter `setCallback(PostCallback)`.

In `MainActivity`:

```
Post post = new Post();
post.setPostCallback(new PostCallback(){

    @Override
    onSuccess((JSONObject data){
        onObtainJSONObject(data);
    }

    @Override
    onError(Exception exception){
        // exception handling ...
    }
});
JSONObject object = post.execute(stringurl, text, "en");
```

In `Post`:

```
private PostCallback callback;
private Exception exception;

public setPostCallback(PostCallback callback){
    this.callback = callback;
}

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args){
     // keep everything as before but when an Exception occurs,
     // assign it to *exception* in the catch block
} 

@Override
public void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject){
    // Note: this will be executed on the main thread
    if(exception == null){
        callback.onSuccess(jsonObject);
    } else {
        callback.onError(exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the method require a return type? And `MainActivity.this` reports it's `not an enclosing class`. And can't I write the code to manipulate the object in the main thread?

Comment: @JouanH.Sulaiman - I assumed that the AsyncTask was an inner class of MainActivity. If it's not then you have to use some kind of callback which will pass the result back to MainActivity. I'll edit my answer to indicate how to do this. (cont)

Comment: (cont) About "can't I write the code to manipulate the object in the main thread?" - usually you don't want to block the main thread in order to wait for the AsyncTask to do its work. That's why one uses callbacks. But the reason that execute() returns the AsyncTask instance is that there is a method get() which blocks the main thread until the execution is finished.

Comment: Sorry this is a yet-to-be-explored territory by me. Does the public interface go in MainActivity or AsyncTask? And the code MainActivity gives a lot of errors, like `Cannot resolve symbol` for PostCallback, @Override not being applicable to constructor, `cannot resolve method` for onObtainJSONObject. I did solve `return type required` for both onSuccess and onError by adding `void`, but the other errors are overwhelming. Thank you a bunch by the way!

Comment: @JouanH.Sulaiman - the `interface` could be standalone or (since it belongs to the `AsyncTask`) be part of the `AsyncTask`. Sometimes you see *"Cannot resolve symbol"*  when you did implement something but it is not `public` so the class you're in can't "see" it. About *"cannot resolve method"*: please make sure you copied the method `onObtainJSONObject(JSONObject)` from the beginning of my answer to `MainActivity`. Since I don't see your code I can't tell what could be wrong with the constructor (of which class?), so no advice there, sorry.